# How to create a linked mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have software that reads only one database by name. However, every day I have to check for records that are 30+ days old so my solution is to rename the database everyday (appending a timestamp) and create a new one with the old name so my software can continue to run.

I need my software to read all of the databases but it can only read one. Is there a way to link the main database with the archived ones without copying the database? I don't think I can use `MERGE` because I won't be able to split the databases by day.

e.g.

- Software only reads database `MAINDB`
- Everyday, a cronjob renames the database. `MAINDB` becomes `BKDB_2015_12_04`. I can still access the database from mysql because it's not a dumped database.
- A new `MAINDB` is made for the software to read.
- However, I need the software to read the data stored in `BKDB_2015_12_04` and any other database `BKDP_*`
- I'd like to have the software, when reading `MAINDB`, also read `BKDB_*`

Essentially, I'm having some databases 'read-only' and I'm partitioning the data by day. I'm reading about using `PARTITION` but I'm dealing with an immense amount of data and I'm not sure if `PARTITION` is effective in dealing with this amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming and re-creating a database is a "bad idea". How can you ever be sure that your database is not being accessed when you rename and re-create?

For example, say I'm in the middle of a purchase and my basket is written to a database table as I add items to it (unlikely scenario but possible). I'm browsing around choosing more items. In the time I'm browsing, the existing database is renamed and a new one re-created. Instantly, my basket is empty with no explanation.

With backups, what happens if your database is renamed half=way through a backup? How can you be sure that all your other renamed databases are backed up?

One final thing - what happens in the long run with renamed databases? Are they left there for ever? Are the dropped after a certain amount of time? etc

If you're checking for records that are 30+ days old, the **only** solution you should be considering is to time-stamp each record. If your tables are linked via single "master" table, put the time-stamp in there. Your queries can stay largely the same (except from adding a check for a times-stamp) and you don't have to calculate database names for the past 30 days

Comment: I currently have the table set up with timestamps but it takes too many hours of downtime for the table to find every instance of 30+ day old records because the table locks as this clean up is being done.

I'm using snort/barnyard so the software can tolerate some downtime. I just don't want to lose visibility for 10 hours. Renaming the database seems quick.

The renamed databases should live for 30 days then be deleted to clear space.

Comment: I don't know how much data you are working on, but if you are under *billions* of rows and it takes 10 hours, there is another problem you should fix...

Comment: To try speeding up, add an index on the timestamp field. It'll increase storage requirements but speed up your query. Also, as @FélixGagnon-Grenier said, if it's taking 10 hours to run, you have other problems that you need to fix

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do queries on all databases with UNION, all you need to know is the names of the databases:

```
select * from MAINDB.table_name
union all
select * from BKDB_2015_12_04.table_name
union all
select * from database_name.table_name
```